# How transform anonymous java class to lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have an application on JavaFX. In this application, I need to implement, the editor of the column. In the old version of the code worked perfectly:

```
myColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<MyRowDataObject, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<MyRowDataObject, String> t) {
                        ((MyRowDataObject) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
);
```

but when I tried to rewrite the code using the lambda

```
myColumn.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent event) ->
                ((MyRowDataObject) event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(event.getNewValue().toString())
);
```

I get an error :Error: java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
Tell me how to specify the type of a lambda expression?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full *generic* type as the parameter for the lambda expression, instead of the *raw* type as you've got it now?

Comment: Your problem is the raw type `CellEditEvent`; if you're going to use a manifest type, make it a full generic type.  But you may be able to elide the type completely and let the compiler infer it.

Comment: _italic_ **bold** myColumn.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<MyRowDataObject, String> event) ->
                        ((MyRowDataObject)event.getTableView().getItems().get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(event.getNewValue().toString())
        );</code> is not work - incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

Comment: If I do not specify the type of the parameter, the compiler indicates an error:java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getNewValue()
  location: variable event of type javafx.event.Event

Comment: Do you mean *'anonymous'*?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone will be interested, turned to compile the code as follows.

```
 myColumn.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
                final TableColumn.CellEditEvent _evn = (TableColumn.CellEditEvent) event;
                ((MyRowDataObject) _evn.getTableView().getItems().get(_evn.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEmail(_evn.getNewValue().toString());
            });
```