# Replacing In-Line Event Handler With Lambda Expression in Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have the following code, and I would like to replace the `EventHandler` with a lambda expression:

```
varName.setOnEditCommit(
    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Attribute, String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Attribute, String> t) {
            System.out.println(t.getNewValue());
        }
    }
);
```

I have tried:

```
varName.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Attribute, String> t)->{
      System.out.println(t.getNewValue());
});
```

But, I get the error:

> incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: What about just `varName.setOnEditCommit(t -> System.out.println(t.getNewValue()));`?

Comment: You might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759765/how-transform-anonymous-java-class-to-lambda-expression for ideas

Comment: I believe the answer will depend on the type of `varName`.  Could you show us that?

Comment: Is `EventHandler` an interface with only one abstract method?

Comment: In most cases, if you have such a problem, you are using *raw types*, either at the declaration of `varName` or the `setOnEditCommit`’s parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the EventHandler when defining the variable:

```
varName.setOnEditCommit((EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Attribute, String>>) t -> 
    System.out.println(t.getNewValue()));
```